# Diffrent behaviour-VisualStudio Debugger against running exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

ediT: I found the reason for the diffrence: only in Visual Studio the input files are opened (They were added to the solution and (more importantly) placed in the solution windows directory), so it worked there.

But when I try to run the generated EXE file it doesn't read those files because of the files path string (worked in VS) "../fileName"

any suggestions (so it will work in both cases)?

In the main code:

```
string testFileName = "LEGACY_R48_800BITS_@40MHz.dat"; //channel output file name
string bitsFileName = "sentBits4.dat"; //original sent bits file name,NO initial zero added

//Works in Visual Studio only 
string path = __FILE__; //gets source code path, include file name
    path = path.substr(0,1+path.find_last_of('\\')); //removes file name
    path1= path+testFileName; //adds input file to path
path2=path+bitsFileName; //adds input file to path


//Works in Application EXE only
path1= testFileName;
path2=bitsFileName;
```

Comment: It could be because on use of uninitialized variables. When running in a debugger, the debugger clears all memory including the stack used by local variables. That means that all values are zero, and pointers are `NULL`. But when running outside the debuggers, these values are undefined and often very random. So if you have a check for `NULL` pointers, but don't initialize the pointer, it will not be `NULL` and the program will use that pointer even though it's not pointing to anything you've allocated, and you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "Working directory" in Visual Studio debugger.

With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
Click the Debug tab.
In the Working directory field, enter the directory from which the project will be launched.

Comment: where I can change it?